# Docker - Unable to use placeholders inside ENTRYPOINT

Tags: java, docker, dockerfile

I have this Dockerfile:

```
FROM java:8
ARG HOST
...
...
ENTRYPOINT java -DHOST=${HOST} -jar ./app.jar
```

I build the docker image passing the necessary build-arg: `docker build -t co/myprogram --build-arg=HOST=myhost.com .`

However when I run the image: `docker run co/myprogram` I get an exception in my program because the placeholder didn't substitute the HOST value. The url looks like http:///action/get instead of http://myhost.com/action/get..

Is there a way to use placehoders in the ENTRYPOINT?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ARGs are not used for interpolating ENTRYPOINT.
To achieve what you want to do, you can add a line with `ENV HOST $HOST`.
The entrypoint will then use $HOST at runtime, rather the interpolated value at buildtime, but, the variable will be set with the default value which was set at buildtime, but is still overridable.

Here is an example:

```
$ cat Dockerfile 
FROM busybox
ARG what
ENV what $what
RUN echo ${what} > /tmp/${what}
ENTRYPOINT cat /tmp/${what}

$ docker run -ti $(docker build -q --build-arg=what=test . ) 
test
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately it seems to be impossible by design: https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/18492